# How to write test cases for Rest API in spring boot..?

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito

I want to write the test case for rest API method please help me in this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/v0.1/getFySectionDetails", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> getFySectionDetails(@RequestBody GstServicesRequestModel gstServicesRequestModel) {
    String gstin = gstServicesRequestModel.getGstin();
    BigInteger reportId = gstServicesRequestModel.getReportId();
    logger.info("Gstin, ReportID : "+gstin+", "+reportId);
    CalculationsVO calculationsVo = gstr1DataHandler.getFySectionDetails(gstin, reportId, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    return new ResponseEntity<CalculationsVO>(calculationsVo, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I am not clear how to write a JUnit test case for it.

Tried but it didn't work:

```
    @Test
    public void getFyMonthlyPurchases() throws Exception {
        String requestBody = "{\"gstin\":\"03AAFFJ4844C1ZS\",\"reportId\":\"20190212122427308\"}";
        mockMvc.perform(post("/gstr1dh/services/v0.1/getFySectionDetails")
                .contentType(PageAttributes.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(requestBody))
                .andExpect(status()
                        .isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$", Matchers.hasSize(1)));
    }
```

Comment: Show some effort by doing something yourself first. Then show us what is not working

Comment: @Test
     public void getFyMonthlyPurchases() throws Exception {
      String requestBody="{\"gstin\":\"03AAFFJ4844C1ZS\",\"reportId\":\"20190212122427308\"}";                                                                                                                 
      mockMvc.perform(post("/gstr1dh/services/v0.1/getFySectionDetails").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(requestBody))
      .andExpect(status().isOk())
      .andExpect(jsonPath("$", Matchers.hasSize(1)));
         
     } I tried this

Comment: Thanks for providing the test code @ANANDVARDHANREDDY. It looks like you're on the right track, can you tell us what isn't working exactly? Does the test fail, and does it provide a message about why it failed? Can you add that to the question please?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski it is saying Request processing failed;Nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException